# Google Push Notifications for Calendar resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, push-notification, google-calendar-api

I've successfully set up Google Calendar API push notifications and it's working fine for users email address.

1. I create a notification channel for specific calendar
2. I create/update/delete events in that calendar
3. Google sends notifications to the webhook that I provided.

But, it doesn't work at all for room email addresses. I can't even create a notification channel (it crashes saying that email address is invalid).
Is it anything that I missed or it's not supported?
I couldn't find any specific notes about that here https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push

Comment: Can you please share the code you are trying to use or any other useful information to try to replicate your issue.

Comment: It's been resolved, I've added the answer below

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.

The reason for not being able to create a notification channel was that the service account didn't have permission to access the resource (room )calendar. As it turned out during the investigation, once DWD (domain-wide delegation) is turned on, it enables access to users' calendars but resources' calendars are not covered.
After adding the following permission
[image]

it started working as expected.